# Same code doesn't work in repeat structure in applescript

Tags: applescript, repeat

I want to remove parts of string after the specific substring.
sample input:

```
"abc def 1987 ghi jkl" "1987"
```

Desired output:

```
"abc def"
```

Now I find this code. It works perfectly.

```
set themovn to "abc def 1987 ghi jkl"
on splitText(theText, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theTextItems
end splitText

set newn to splitText(themovn, "1987")
set newn to text item 1 of newn
```

But the substring maybe other values. It's a group. So I use repaet:

```
set themovn to "abc def 1987 ghi jkl"
set allkeys to {"1987", "1080", "720"}

repeat with akey in allkeys
    set newn to splitText(themovn, akey)
    set newn to text item 1 of newn
end repeat

on splitText(theText, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theTextItems
end splitText
```

What's interesting is it doesn't work. Maybe it's not the right way to use handler. So I remove the handler to test:

```
set themovn to "abc def 1987 ghi jkl"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "1987"
set theTextItems to every text item of themovn
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
set newn to theTextItems

set newn to text item 1 of newn
```

It works well. The output is correct. Then I put it in repeat structure:

```
set themovn to "abc def 1987 ghi jkl"
set allkeys to {"1987", "1080p", "720"}

repeat with akey in allkeys
    try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to akey
        set theTextItems to every text item of themovn
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set newn to theTextItems

        set newn to text item 1 of newn
    end try
end repeat

return newn
```

Doesn't work. So I want to know why the same code doesn't work in repeat structure.

Comment: You are resetting the value of `newn` each time through the loop, so you are just getting the results from the last delimiter.  Note that the text item delimiter can be a _list_.

Comment: @red_menace Got it. Solved. Thank you very much!